# Specific rearrangement of elements in list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an $n\times n$ matrix `G` with elements `g[i,j]` that I construct with
`Table[g[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]`

I have tried without success to write a code without loops in Mathematica that rearranges these elements to a vector in a certain way.

To illustrate the case $n=4$:
$$
G=\begin{pmatrix}
g[1,1]&g[1,2]&g[1,3]&g[1,4]\\g[2,1]&g[2,2]&g[2,3]&g[2,4]\\g[3,1]&g[3,2]&g[3,3]
&g[3,4]\\g[4,1]&g[4,2]&g[4,3]&g[4,4]\end{pmatrix} \longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
g[1,1]-g[2,2]\\g[2,2]-g[3,3]\\g[3,3]-g[4,4]\\g[1,2]-g[2,3]\\g[2,3]-g[3,4]\\g[2,1]-g[3,2]\\g[3,2]-g[4,3]
\end{pmatrix} = \widetilde{G}
$$

I.e, I'm trying to find a way to create a vector where every element is a subtraction between two diagonally consecutive elements in $G$, starting on the central diagonal, working its way to the right and then starting over under the central diagonal working its way to the left. For a fixed $n$ this could easily be done manually, but with my limitations in Mathematica I have not found a way to do this with arbitrary integers.

Comment: Ponder on `Join @@ Table[-Differences[Diagonal[G, k]], {k, {0, 1, -1}}]`.

Comment: @0x4A4D : Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k = Table[g[i, j], {i, 4}, {j, 4}]; 
Flatten[Diagonal[k[[;; -2, ;; -2]] - k[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]], #] & /@ {0, 1, -1}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Since it seems to suit the OP's needs:

```
G = Array[g, {4, 4}];
Join @@ Table[-Differences[Diagonal[G, k]], {k, {0, 1, -1}}]
   {g[1, 1] - g[2, 2], g[2, 2] - g[3, 3], g[3, 3] - g[4, 4], g[1, 2] - g[2, 3],
    g[2, 3] - g[3, 4], g[2, 1] - g[3, 2], g[3, 2] - g[4, 3]}
```

The key here is the use of `Diagonal[]` to extract the diagonals of a matrix (note the second argument for picking which diagonal to extract), and the use of `Differences[]` to generate the needed entries; however, the sign is opposite from what the OP needed, so we perform a negation afterwards. `Join[]` merely strings together the three diagonals thus extracted into a single list.

Answer (score 1):

***Partition* with its undocumented 6-argument form:**

```
gG = Array[g, {4, 4}];
Join @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1, None, {}, Subtract] & /@
   (Diagonal[gG, #] & /@ {0, 1, -1})) // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  g(1,1)-g(2,2) \\
>  g(2,2)-g(3,3) \\
>  g(3,3)-g(4,4) \\
>  g(1,2)-g(2,3) \\
>  g(2,3)-g(3,4) \\
>  g(2,1)-g(3,2) \\
>  g(3,2)-g(4,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

***BlockMap***

```
Join @@ (BlockMap[Subtract @@ # &, #, 2, 1] & /@ 
  (Diagonal[gG, #] & /@ {0, 1, -1}))
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  g(1,1)-g(2,2) \\
>  g(2,2)-g(3,3) \\
>  g(3,3)-g(4,4) \\
>  g(1,2)-g(2,3) \\
>  g(2,3)-g(3,4) \\
>  g(2,1)-g(3,2) \\
>  g(3,2)-g(4,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$